Allow a service to access on shared network folder
An active directory user is specified to start one of my services. The service launches correctly but when the task associated with the service is launched, it is impossible for the service to have access to a network shared folder on another server in the same domain even though the user has the necessary rights to access it.
Is there a way to allow this service to access the shared folder on the network? Without authorizing the entire server (NAME$ for exemple)?
Thank you for your help
The rights of the active directory user is good
